# The mapping of CLR type to EDM type is ambiguous - works in some machines

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, edmx

We are facing a specific scenario with EF (using 6.2).

We have a framework library which uses some of the common entities(framework related tables like Users, Roles, Access etc.) and the DAL uses all Database tables/views (including the framework's). so we have EDMX in framework project with subset of tables and DAL has another EDMX with full DB ref.

Now this is working fine in one of the machine where the framework libraries are built. while we copy the framework dlls and rest of project code to another dev machine, we are getting the CLR mapping issue, that to for some of the entities (not all).

We tried with recreating the DAL's EDMX and reset the references in vain.
The configuration and other libraries seems to be same in both machines.

Unfortunately we cannot change EDMX file manually, as multiple developers keep working the the project with frequent EDMX updates. So each time updating may not be a best bet.

Comment: Can you post any code, error message to clarify?

Answer (score 0):

Just figured out that both the connection string (framework's and DAL's) in the non-working machine were referring to single model, which is causing the problem..

```
<add name="CoreDBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.CoreDBModel.csdl|res://*/Models.CoreDBModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.CoreDBModel.msl;

<add name="AppDBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.CoreDBModel.csdl|res://*/Models.CoreDBModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.CoreDBModel.msl;
```